# How to include a struct with a named lifetime inside a struct without a named lifetime?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to include `apache_avro::Writer` inside a struct I define. My struct implements multiple traits, and those methods mutate the struct. You can think of the traits as event handlers and my struct is intended to log the events to avro.

Ideally, I'd like the lifetime of the `Writer` contained in my struct to match the lifetime of my struct, but I can't use `'_` in the definition. I also tried adding a named lifetime to MyStruct, but run into issues because then I think I need to add that to all the traits MyStruct implements to ensure that all the `&mut self` references have the same right lifetime.

Here's a minimal [playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d3f74a05d313f42d65a5f4df35699325)

```
pub struct Writer<'a, W> {
    bar: &'a u64,
}

use std::fs::File;

trait TraitMyStructNeedsToImplement {
    fn foo(&mut self);
}

struct MyStruct {
    writer: Writer<'_, File>,
}

impl TraitMyStructNeedsToImplement for MyStruct {
    fn foo(&mut self) {
        todo!();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you add a lifetime parameter to the struct?

Comment: This is impossible without using unsafe. Ideally just add a parameter to `MyStruct`

Comment: When I add a parameter to `MyStruct`, I run into errors on `impl TraitMy...` saying:expected fn pointer `fn(&mut MyStruct<'a>)`  found fn pointer `fn(&'a mut MyStruct<'a>)`

Comment: Here's what it looks like in playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8aad5088474f016ef7e308869869d453

Comment: One thing I'm wondering is if using `std::marker::PhantomData` would help. I end up creating the `Writer` in `MyStruct::foo()` in my actual code, which is why I need `'a` lifetime in `foo()` I think.

Comment: Why did you add `'a` to `&mut self` when implementing the trait? Its wrong for multiple reasons and it works without it: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fd28daffcaadf636920e28590fd34b49)

Comment: I made a new example that's more realistic [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4db8eda070d0bbfe79053c048f254757) which gives me this error I don't know how to resolve `assignment requires that '1 must outlive 'a`

Comment: So I've managed to workaround this in my actual code using `apache_avro::Writer` by making the reference `Writer` uses `'a` on static, which works in this situation but I think I'm still misunderstanding how to handle this problem in general.

Comment: Ok I figured out the issue. Thanks @kmdreko, your pointer that I don't need 'a on mut self helped me see which way to go to resolve the issue.